# Construction of a closed subset of irrationals

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Let $S=[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and let $A\subset S$ be a closed subset with a positive Lebesgue measure ($=\mathcal{L}(A)>0$).

I want to show the following.
Let $b\in[0, \mathcal{L}(A))$ then there exists a closed subset $B\subset A$ such that $\mathcal{L}(B)=b$.

This is just my assumption and I am not sure if the statement holds. Hence, I would appreciate any hints that would help me prove/disapprove this statement.

Comment: For any set $A$ of finite measure, the function $t\mapsto \mathcal L(A\cap (-\infty,t])$ is continuous, and it goes to zero at $-\infty$ and goes to $\mathcal L(A)$ at $+\infty$. From this, it follows that there exists $t$ such that $L(A\cap (-\infty,t])=b$. The continuity of the above function follows simply by the continuity of the Lebesgue measure. And the set $B=A\cap (-\infty,t]$ is closed because is intersection of closed sets.

Comment: In the context of the posed question, should I choose $t\to \mathcal{L}(A\cap(-\infty, t])$.  This way $A\cap(-\infty, t]$ will be a closed subset of $A$ for any $t\in (-\infty , \infty)$ and thus set $B:=A\cap(-\infty, t_b]$ for which $\mathcal{L}(B)=b$?

Comment: Yep. Sorry, I was editing the comment to make it match the question

Comment: This helps, thanks!